# Permanent redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I recently changed how my blog can be reached.

The new way:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(\/*)$ blog.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/page-([0-9]*)$ blog.php?p=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ blog.php?handle=$1 [QSA]
```

The old way was:

```
RewriteRule ^news(\/*)$ blog.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/page-([0-9]*)$ blog.php?p=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ blog.php?handle=$1 [QSA]
```

So basically only the word "news" changed to "blog".

Is there a simple way to make a permanent redirect from `/news` to `/blog` aswell as `/news/*` to `/blog/*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to make a permanent redirect from `/news` to `/blog` as well as `/news/*` to `/blog/*`

Place this rule as first rule below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]*)?/news(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/blog%2 [L,NE,R=301]

# remaining rules go here
```

Comment: This redirects me from `http://localhost/projectname/news` to `http://localhost/blog/projectname/news` in my test system

Comment: That's only for my localhost test environment. The live server does not have the projectname part. The solution has to work for both though. The rewrites in the original post also worked for both. (Note: On localhost, the .htaccess is located inside the "projectname" folder, as are all other project files)

Comment: May I ask why this information is not part of your question?

Comment: It seemed not relevant to me, since it should work from the directory where the htacccess is located. I don't have a RewriteBase. Never needed one. All rewrites worked perfectly fine until now.

Comment: Well if it is relevant for comments section then it must belong to question. Also presence of two different directory systems in two environments is very important for question.

Comment: check my edited rule to make it work in both environments.

Comment: Now on the live server it would also redirect `www.example.com/something/news/something` to `www.example.com/something/blog/something`. Isn't it possible to have the rule only apply to the current directory, like the rules in the original post do?

Comment: Your code has no redirect rule and there is difference between redirect and rewrite rules. Rewrite rule targets can have relative paths but redirect rule targets need full path. btw you wrote earlier URLs were `/news/*` so this `/something/news` won't even be there.

Comment: If you want to be specific then use: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/projectname)?/news(/.*)?$ [NC]` in condition above.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that redirects need to be absolute. I'll have to work with that then

Comment: Only way you can avoid absolute paths in redirect when you use correct `RewriteBase` at the top.